# Suspending All Threads Message

Tags: android, android-activity, camera

i am working on an android app. I have 2 Activities, MainActivity Calls an intent which use my CameraActivity which is described bellow.

```
public class CameraActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE = 100;
    private static final int REQUEST_VIDEO = 200;
    private static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 300;

    Button mCaptureButton;
    Button mGalleryButton;
    ImageView mImageView;
    TextView mText;
    File mDestination;
    int mMediaType = 0;

    Uri mAttachedImage = null;

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        mCaptureButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.capture);
        mCaptureButton.setOnClickListener(mCameraListener);

        mGalleryButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        mCaptureButton.setOnClickListener(mGalleryListener);

        mGalleryButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        mCaptureButton.setOnClickListener(mSendListener);

        mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.file);

        //Generar una codificación para el nombre
        //mCurrentPhotoPath = this.getImageFileName();
        //mDestination = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), mCurrentPhotoPath + ".jpg");
        mDestination = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImage.jpg");

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_camera, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    String getImageFileName()
    {
        String mTimeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String sImgFileName = "GPS_JPG_" + mTimeStamp;
        return sImgFileName;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //PAra imágenes
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && mMediaType == 0) {
            //Process and display the image
            try{
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mDestination);
                //BitmapFactory.Options mOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                //mOptions.inSampleSize = 1; //Para reducir el tamaño del archivo
                //Bitmap userImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, mOptions);
                Bitmap userImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(userImage);
            }catch ( Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Bitmap userImage = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            //mImageView.setImageBitmap(userImage);
        }
        //Para Video
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && mMediaType == 1) {
            try{
                String mLocation = data.getData().toString();
                mText.setText(mLocation);
            }catch ( Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //Para la Galería
        if(requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try{
                Uri mSelectedImageTmp = data.getData();
                InputStream mImageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(mSelectedImageTmp);
                Bitmap mSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mImageStream);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(mSelectedImage);
            }catch ( Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Llama al procedimiento de tomar fotos
     */
    private View.OnClickListener mCameraListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                //Agregar codigo para diferenciar Foto de Video
                if( mMediaType == 0){

                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    mIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mDestination));
                    if (mIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivityForResult(mIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                    //Add (optional) extra to save video to our file
                    mIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mDestination));
                    //Optional extra to set video quality
                    mIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
                    if (mIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivityForResult(mIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO);
                    }
                }
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                //Handle if no application exists
            }
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener mGalleryListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try{
                //Intent mPhotoSelectIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                Intent mPhotoSelectIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                mPhotoSelectIntent.setType("image/*");

                if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18){
                    mPhotoSelectIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                }

                startActivityForResult(mPhotoSelectIntent, SELECT_IMAGE);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Procedimiento para envíar la data al server
     */
    private View.OnClickListener mSendListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };


}
```

So the problem is that i am getting the followin messages, and the intent which open the camera appears to be suspended. I am new in Android, so what am i doing wrong?

Hope you could help me.

This is my Logcat

```
03-10 21:30:54.340    1916-1916/sarode.muninews I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-10 21:30:55.005    1916-1923/sarode.muninews W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 43.166ms
03-10 21:30:55.101    1916-1928/sarode.muninews W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 66.286ms
03-10 21:30:55.108    1916-1928/sarode.muninews I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1801(119KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 465KB/623KB, paused 69.733ms total 328.923ms
03-10 21:30:55.291    1916-1928/sarode.muninews W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 56.251ms
03-10 21:30:55.296    1916-1928/sarode.muninews I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 113(33KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 52% free, 456KB/968KB, paused 58.321ms total 172.911ms
03-10 21:30:55.454    1916-1934/sarode.muninews D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
03-10 21:30:55.456    1916-1916/sarode.muninews D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6dae620, tid 1916
03-10 21:30:55.466    1916-1916/sarode.muninews D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
03-10 21:30:55.570    1916-1928/sarode.muninews I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2902(177KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 17% free, 799KB/968KB, paused 6.153ms total 62.260ms
03-10 21:30:55.598    1916-1934/sarode.muninews D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6dae9a0, tid 1934
03-10 21:30:55.618    1916-1934/sarode.muninews I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-10 21:30:55.664    1916-1934/sarode.muninews D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-10 21:30:55.677    1916-1934/sarode.muninews W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-10 21:30:55.677    1916-1934/sarode.muninews W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6d956c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-10 21:30:56.741    1916-1928/sarode.muninews I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 178(24KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 5% free, 914KB/968KB, paused 4.185ms total 268.968ms
03-10 21:30:56.876    1916-1916/sarode.muninews I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-10 21:30:56.962    1916-1923/sarode.muninews W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 63.663ms
03-10 21:30:56.992    1916-1928/sarode.muninews I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 257(38KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 36% free, 892KB/1404KB, paused 2.726ms total 141.552ms
03-10 21:31:02.298    1916-1934/sarode.muninews W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-10 21:31:02.298    1916-1934/sarode.muninews W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5c536c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-10 21:31:17.536    1916-1934/sarode.muninews W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-10 21:31:17.536    1916-1934/sarode.muninews W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5c536c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-10 21:31:17.752    1916-1923/sarode.muninews W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 19.847ms
03-10 21:31:17.775    1916-1928/sarode.muninews I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2825(130KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 1227KB/1404KB, paused 3.490ms total 299.942ms
03-10 21:31:17.820    1916-1928/sarode.muninews W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 44.499ms
03-10 21:31:18.107    1916-1916/sarode.muninews W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
03-10 21:31:22.990    1916-1923/sarode.muninews W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 9.156ms
03-10 21:31:23.015    1916-1928/sarode.muninews I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 716(30KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 11% free, 1246KB/1404KB, paused 28.796ms total 60.860ms
03-10 21:31:23.039    1916-1928/sarode.muninews W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 22.880ms
03-10 21:31:29.149    1916-1928/sarode.muninews I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 776(36KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 1255KB/1404KB, paused 23.451ms total 30.459ms
03-10 21:31:32.767    1916-1923/sarode.muninews W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.871ms
03-10 21:31:33.725    1916-1928/sarode.muninews W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 22.085ms
03-10 21:31:34.611    1916-1928/sarode.muninews I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 459(20KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 9% free, 1266KB/1404KB, paused 33.821ms total 73.711ms
03-10 21:31:35.828    1916-1928/sarode.muninews I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1438(72KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 1218KB/1730KB, paused 2.764ms total 219.659ms
03-10 21:31:35.845    1916-1928/sarode.muninews W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 16.503ms
03-10 21:32:11.825    1916-1923/sarode.muninews W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 12.
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -6):

checking my code, i've found all my buttons were bad assigned to their listerners. After doing some changes, all was running as i wish.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post the working code?  I'm having the same problem and would like to see what you did to fix your problem.